# jQuery | Swapping one div's nested image src with another div's nested image source on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking to pass the image source of a clicked item into the div of another. For example in the following markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="header">
    <img src='placeholder' />
  </div>
</div>
<!--row-->

<div class="thumb-wrapper row">
  <div class="thumb">
    <div class="thumb-content">
      <img src="http://static.srcdn.com/slir/w700-h350-q90-c700:350/wp-content/uploads/hulk-mark-ruffalo-marvel-phase-3-movies.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="thumb">
    <div class="thumb-content">
      <img src="https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/spider-mannew.jpeg?w=670&h=377&crop=1" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the user to change the image source in the header to whatever image src is within the thumb-content div of the clicked thumb.

I've gotten this to work on a single thumb basis, but I'm not sure how to make it work for many thumbs:

```
$('.thumb ').on('click', function(e) {
  $("#header img").attr("src", "http://placekitten.com/1200/800");
});
```

Another factor here, the function needs to specifically target the image within the **thumb-content** div as there may be another image in the **thumb** div.

Appreciate any direction or help.

Answer (score 2):

Retrieve the `src` attribute of the child `img` element based on the element that was clicked:

```
$('.thumb').on('click', function(e) {
  var src = $(this).find('.thumb-content img').attr('src');
  $("#header img").attr("src", src);
});
```

You could simplify your code and attach the event listener to the `img` elements instead:

```
$('.thumb img').on('click', function(e) {
  $("#header img").attr("src", this.src);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this, using child selectors?

```
$('.thumb-content>img').click(function(e) {
    console.log('thumb clicked');
    $("#header>img").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$("#header img").attr("src", $(this).find('img').attr("src"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$('.thumb img').on('click', function(){
    $('header img').remove();
    $(this).clone().appendTo('header');
});
```